# Saving each iteration of a repeat loop to a vector - R

Tags: r, loops

I've looked through previous help threads and haven't found something that has helped me with this specific problem. I know that a for loop would be a better way to generate the same data, but I'm interested in making this work with a repeat loop (mostly just as an exercise) and am struggling with the solution.

So I'm looping to create 3 iterations of 100 rnorm observations, changing the means each time from 5, to 25, to 45.

```
i <- 1
repeat{
    x <- rnorm(100, mean = j, sd = 3)
    j <- 5*i 
    i <- i + 4
    if (j > 45) break
    cat(x, "\n",j, "\n")
}
```

All of my tinkering to get a combined saved output for each iteration (for a total of 300 values) has failed. Help!

Comment: You did not define your `j` before repeat. I.e. `i <- 1; j <- 1; repeat { ...`

Comment: You don't have to define `j` before the repeat, but you do have to define it before you use it as an argument to `rnorm`.

Comment: @LizzieSilver true, in general. However, in this case, it's better to do that before "repeat". Otherwise _mean_ would be always _j_

Comment: @E.Go.: if @ccoxen defines `j` as above, i.e. `j <- 5*i`, then I don't see the problem.

Comment: True, i.e. switching the position of `x <- rnorm(...)` and `j <- 5*i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what structure of data do you want.
For lists it would be:

```
r = list()
repeat{

r[[length(r)+1]] = list(x,j)
}
```

Then: `r[[1]][[1]]` will be x for 1 loop and r[[1]][[2]] would be j.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lapply to get this:

```
lapply(c(5,25,45), function(x){
  rnorm(100, mean = x, sd = 3)
  })
```

This will give you a list with 3 elements:
Each containing 100 observations drawn from the respective normal-distribution.

Comment: Like you've shown, other loops are better methods for generating these data. I was just interested in the method for storing each iteration of a repeat loop. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Since you know how many observations you want to store, you can pre-allocate a matrix of that size, and store the data in it as it's generated.

```
# preallocate the space for the values you want to store
x <- matrix(nrow=100, ncol=3)

# save the three means in a vector
j_vals <- c(5,25,45)

# if you really need a repeat loop you can do it like so:
i <- 1
repeat {

    # save the random sample in a column of the matrix x
    x[,i] <- rnorm(100, mean = j_vals[i], sd = 3)

    # print the random sample to the console (you can omit this)
    cat(x[,i], "\n",j_vals[i], "\n")

    i <- i+1
    if (i > 3) break
}
```

You should get out a matrix `x` with the random samples stored in the columns. You can access each column like `x[,1]`, `x[,2]` etc.